# localRotation applied to children not being applied

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am constructing a fractal tree using cylinders which are placed at 45 degrees rotation from the last cylinder and the position shifted slightly so it's at the end of the parent branch.

Position and scale work fine, but only the first child of the fractal gets an x rotation of 45. The rest are all 0. If I set the child of the first child to 50, then the rotation becomes 5.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Fractal : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int maxDepth;
    private int depth;
    [SerializeField] int numChildren;
    [SerializeField] GameObject branchPrefab;

    void Initialize(Fractal parent)
    {
        branchPrefab = parent.branchPrefab;
        maxDepth = parent.maxDepth;
        depth = parent.depth + 1;
        numChildren = parent.numChildren;

        transform.parent = parent.transform;

        transform.localScale = Vector3.one / 2;
        transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 1, 0.5f);
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(45, 0, 0);
    }

    void SetParent(Transform child, Transform parent)
    {
        child.parent = parent;
        child.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
        child.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;
        child.localScale = Vector3.one;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        if (depth < maxDepth)
        {
            new GameObject("Fractal child " + depth + 1 + "/").AddComponent<Fractal>().Initialize(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you aren't creating the objects in `Awake` or `OnEnable` instead of `Start`? As written, it seems like you haven't shared enough information to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I looked very hard at it, without any luck... so I tried it and it works :shrug:
The mistake is somewhere else.

Comment: also worked for me https://ibb.co/XCVqYd0